# why the classification models use top5 accuracy in evaluation metrics?

Tags: classification, resnet, mobilenet

I was checking the evaluation metrics in Resnet and Mobilenet and I was wondering why top5 accuracy is used for evaluation metrics? The highest probability will be selected and top1 accuracy is the best for these applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example train different models (or same models but with different training methods or having different weights in general), and pick the top 5 (for example) performing models which give the best top-5 accuracy. Then (assuming you have enough resources and computing power) you can rank the top 5 predictions of each model and apply some formula to rank the best prediction overall.
For example, when testing on some sample, all of the 5 models are ranking the correct classification as second, but the first prediction is different in each of them, so according to your ranking algorithm the correct prediction should have better rank than all of the other predictions since it ranked second in all of the models.